# What is the SQL ''LIKE" equivalent on Django ORM queries?

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models, django-orm

What is the equivalent of the following `SQL` statement in `Django`?

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE string LIKE pattern;
```

I tried this:

```
result = table.objects.filter( pattern in string )
```

but it didn't work. How can I implement it?

Answer (score 322, accepted):

Use [`__contains`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#std-fieldlookup-contains) or [`__icontains`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#icontains) (case-insensitive):

```py
result = table.objects.filter(string__contains='pattern')
```

The SQL equivalent is

```
SELECT ... WHERE string LIKE '%pattern%';
```

@Dmitri's [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33940147/392985) covers patterns like 'pattern%' or '%pattern'

Comment: And for case insensitive search use **__icontains** ->
`result = table.objects.filter(string__icontains='pattern')`

Comment: This answer only covers a subset of the possible patterns. It wouldn't handle a pattern like `%a%b%`.

Comment: @kasperd, try: `result = table.objects.filter(string__contains='a').filter(string__contains='b')`

Comment: @LS That would match `ba` which `LIKE %a%b%` would not.

Comment: @falsetru What about cases like these? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57004942/django-orms-contains-vs-sqls-like

Comment: This answer is incomplete for the reasons stated above. It should also include the information in @Dmitry's answer.

Comment: @medley56,  OP mentioned `pattern in string` which correspond to `__contains`. And I thought people will follow the link in the answer, they can find another field lookup options. As Dmitriy already answered, I'll leave my answer as is. Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: See the [answer by Petr Dlouhý below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59972954/2810305) for a proper answer that handles all SQL LIKE patterns.

Comment: @falsetru The OP's question is where string like pattern, and the pattern can be anything. So I spent quite a bit of time putting in a % in the pattern and wondering why it didn't work till I read Dmitri's answer. So I suggest its worth mentioning the point here. Thanks

Answer (score 56):

contains and icontains mentioned by falsetru make queries like `SELECT ... WHERE headline LIKE '%pattern%`

Along with them, you might need these ones with similar behavior:
[startswith](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#startswith), [istartswith](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#istartswith), [endswith](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#endswith), [iendswith](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#iendswith)

making

`SELECT ... WHERE headline LIKE 'pattern%`

or

`SELECT ... WHERE headline LIKE '%pattern`

Answer (score 29):

This can be done with [Django's custom lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-lookups/). I have made the lookup into a [Django-like-lookup application](https://github.com/PetrDlouhy/django-like-lookup). After installing it the `__like` lookup with the `%` and `_` wildcards will be enabled.

All the necessary code in the application is:

```
from django.db.models import Lookup
from django.db.models.fields import Field


@Field.register_lookup
class Like(Lookup):
    lookup_name = 'like'

    def as_sql(self, compiler, connection):
        lhs, lhs_params = self.process_lhs(compiler, connection)
        rhs, rhs_params = self.process_rhs(compiler, connection)
        params = lhs_params + rhs_params
        return '%s LIKE %s' % (lhs, rhs), params
```

Comment: This is the proper answer to the question, unlike the accepted answer.

Comment: This is pretty cool, but is there any risk of user being able to pass dirty data into the query?

Comment: This is the correct answer. With the answer I could never add a middle %...

Answer (score 9):

```
result = table.objects.filter(string__icontains='pattern')
```

Case insensitive search for string in a field.

Comment: Nice, but the same answer had already been given almost three years earlier.

Answer (score 4):

In order to preserve the order of the words as in the sql LIKE '%pattern%' statement I use iregex, for example:

```
qs = table.objects.filter(string__iregex=pattern.replace(' ', '.*'))
```

string methods are immutable so your pattern variable will not change and with .* you'll be looking for 0 or more occurrences of any character but break lines.

By using the following to iterate over the pattern words:

```
qs = table.objects
for word in pattern.split(' '):
    qs = qs.filter(string__icontains=word)
```

the order of the words in your pattern will not be preserved, for some people that could work but in the case of trying to mimic the sql like statement I'll use the first option.

Comment: You might want to make the replacement `.*?` to have lazy matching and not consume the whole string.

Answer (score 3):

full example : lets say we have table called DjangTable with string field name file_name and we want to create Django filter equivalent to the query that match space in the string file_name in mysql:

```
SELECT * FROM DjangTable WHERE file_name LIKE '% %' 
class DjangTable(UTModel):


    ...
    file_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    ...
```

in Django using python it will be :

```
pattern = ' ' # same as mysql LIKE '% %'
DjangTable.objects.filter(file_name__contains=pattern)
```

Answer (score 0):

**SQL "LIKE" equivalent on Django ORM queries:**

**SQL Query:**

```
SELECT * or any_column_name 
FROM table_name
WHERE string LIKE '%pattern%';
```

**Equivalent Django ORM Query Pattern:**

```
qs = Model.objects.filter(column_name__contains='string_pattern')
```

**Equivalent Django ORM Query Example: If the model is: Book and column is: id, name etc. then the ORM Query will be like below:**

```
qs = Book.objects.filter(name__contains='programming')
```