# django query if charfield value is within another string

Tags: python, django

I know i could use `__in` on a list like but what about something like python's:

```
# might not be able to separate on whitespace
'abc' in 'this_is a stringwith_abc+in it'
```

except I do not want to split the string into a list because I can't be sure of the character on which to split.

So something like:

```
Model.objects.filter(charfield__in='blob of text to find field value within')
```

edit1:

`__contained` is not what I am looking for, if anything a `__contained_by` method would be the solution

Comment: I'm not sure how you would achieve this with Djano's QuerySet syntax, but at first glance it seems like any query like this will require a full table scan. Even with a linear time search on the text blob, you'll have to search ever row in your table.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sql "LIKE" equivalent in django query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18140838/sql-like-equivalent-in-django-query)

Comment: @KeyanP Even if it was one of many kwargs or multiple appended `.filter()` methods?

Comment: Your question isn't still very clear. Given a constant string S, Is it that for each row X in the table, you want to know S contains X ?

Comment: @e4c5 I would like to find if a sub-string (model field) is present within another string (constant). So to try and match your example: Given a constant string S, for each column X in the table, I want to know if X contains S.

Comment: @e4c5 the best comparison I can currently think of is the `__contained_by` query for lists except for a string