# Queries with LIKE (sql) equivalent in Python and string description

Tags: python, sql, django, string

I want to make a query in python using the equivalent of LIKE in sql.
So for I've been using the __contains option like this :

```
results = objectName.objects.filter(variable__contains='someword')
```

But now I want to put a constraint on the variable like :

```
filter(variable__contains='_A%')
```

with "_" being any character and "%" all character it wants - like in SQL - but it doesn't work :(
Does someone know how to do this ?

Comment: Thats `filter(variable__startswith='_A')`.

Comment: Try defining it with raw string like `r"_A%"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sql "LIKE" equivalent in django query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18140838/sql-like-equivalent-in-django-query)

Comment: It doesn't work because it's looking for the exact character underscore, or I want it to be replace by any character

Comment: @DusanGligoric: this will not help, since `'_A%' == r'_A%'`. A raw stream is not a special stream, it is used to avoid a lot of escaping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django's queries don't seem to support LIKE out of the box (which is kind of weird).

You can translate your `LIKE` expression to a regular expression and use [`__regex`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#regex):

```
.filter(variable__regex='.A.*')
```

(Another, more advanced way would be to write the LIKE lookup class yourself and register it on CharField.)