# Django ORM's contains vs SQL's LIKE

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models, django-orm

I'm working on Django **2.1.5** and MySQL **14.14**.

I'm trying to query using a wildcard search as below for single character replacement.

- `98765?321` - returns all the numbers in the database column with a single replacement for `?` - at most `10` numbers will be returned.
- `98?65?321` - returns all the numbers with single replacement for both `?`s - at most `100` numbers will be returned.
- `98?65?32?` - returns all the numbers with single replacement for **first** `?` and all the numbers ending with that for **second** `?`- any number of numbers could be returned.
- `98?65?3?1` - returns all the numbers with single replacement for all three `?`s - at most `1000` numbers will be returned.
- `987?` should return all the numbers starting with `987` - could return any number of numbers.

I was able to do this with `Model.objects.filter(column_regex=regex)`.

But as the DB contains 50 millions of rows, this is impacting performance.

How can I do the same thing with `column__contains` or `column__icontains` etc.

Sample DB column values:

```
9875156245
7657676372
3765277678
7765725757
```

Comment: Can you provide your regex and column value samples?

Comment: updated in the question.

Comment: Yes, but what was the regex?

Comment: The regex cases were already explained in the question.