# Django REST Framework GET to retrieve rows that have NAME LIKE %NAME%

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

So I have a table which I want to query using GET request and it should return me the items that match the %NAME% but currently the request returns me the complete table with all entries, not what I want.

**request**

```
http://localhost:8000/inventory/?name=cookie/
```

**response**

```
GET /inventory/?name=cookie/
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: POST, OPTIONS, GET
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

[
    {
        "item_code": "61f6ccca-e822-4b36-9ddf-5ec79a55a184",
        "name": "Golden Nutella Filled Cookie",
        "price": 100,
        "description": "Delicious Nutella-filled homemade cookie which will satisfy your cravings.",
        "image": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1499636136210-6f4ee915583e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=700&q=80",
        "quantity": 12
    },
    {
        "item_code": "ef6f68c4-c9a3-4a4e-8d5a-14d8f75a01ba",
        "name": "Fudgy Dark Brownie",
        "price": 60,
        "description": "Fudgy and chewy dark chocolate passion.",
        "image": "https://bakerbynature.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Cocoa-Fudge-Brownies-1-of-1.jpg",
        "quantity": 16
    }
]
```

**expected response**

```
[
    {
        "item_code": "61f6ccca-e822-4b36-9ddf-5ec79a55a184",
        "name": "Golden Nutella Filled Cookie",
        "price": 100,
        "description": "Delicious Nutella-filled homemade cookie which will satisfy your cravings.",
        "image": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1499636136210-6f4ee915583e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=700&q=80",
        "quantity": 12
    },
]
```

MODEL: **Inventory**

```
import uuid
from django.db import models


class Inventory(models.Model):
    item_code = models.UUIDField(
        primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False)
    price = models.IntegerField(null=False)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    image = models.URLField()
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Item: {self.name} - Price:{self.price}'
```

**views.py**

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def inventory_list(request):

    if request.method == 'GET':
        inventory = Inventory.objects.all()
        serializer = InventorySerializer(inventory, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = InventorySerializer(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

> EDIT (used name__icontains=name) for %NAME%

```
@api_view(['GET', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
def inventory_item(request, name):
    try:
        item = Inventory.objects.get(name__icontains=name)
    except Inventory.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        serializer = InventorySerializer(item)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'PUT':
        serializer = InventorySerializer(item, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    elif request.method == 'DELETE':
        item.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class InventorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Inventory
        fields = ['item_code', 'name', 'price',
                  'description', 'image', 'quantity']
```

APP NAME: api **urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', inventory_list),
    path('<str:name>/', inventory_item)
]
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('inventory/', include('api.urls'))
]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Did you try this related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18140838/sql-like-equivalent-in-django-query ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sql "LIKE" equivalent in django query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18140838/sql-like-equivalent-in-django-query)

Comment: I added an edit to views.py and dused name__icontains=name but still the output is same

Comment: I think I must add that I am using postgresql as my database

Comment: @ManuelCarrero , sadly it does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how your view should be, for retrieving items. Check answer by [Eric Andrews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150505/capturing-url-parameters-in-request-get) on how to capture GET data.

```
@api_view(['GET', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
def inventory_item(request):

    if request.method == 'GET':
        name = request.GET.get('name')
        try:
            items = Inventory.objects.filter(name__icontains=name)
            serializer = InventorySerializer(items, many=True)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        except Inventory.DoesNotExist:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

Class Based View Example:

```
class GetItemFromInventoryView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = InventorySerializer
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        name = self.request.query_params.get('name')
        queryset = Inventory.objects.filter(name__icontains=name)
        return queryset
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: One more thing i don't know how you are updating or deleting data based on name, because it will return multiple queries. Since you are using `%NAME%` which will be part of a string and it will return multiple items. Be careful with that.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I am not deleting based on name, just retrieving items based on that.

Comment: Then above should suffice your needs :)