# How to use Sqlite string pattern matching from Django?

Tags: python, django, sqlite

If I have a `CharField` in a Django model, and I try to filter it using a string pattern with the `LIKE` operator, such as:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(text__like='he_lo')
```

Django returns the error:

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unsupported lookup 'like' for CharField or join on the field not permitted.
```

However, if I use `manage.py dbshell` to run the raw SQL:

```
select * from myapp_mymodel where text like 'he_lo';
```

it runs just fine.

Why does Django disallow pattern matching in it's ORM even though Sqlite supports it?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18140838/sql-like-equivalent-in-django-query) answer your question?

Comment: @RichardNeumann Sort of. Django's `__contains` is  a wrapper around `LIKE`, not a simple alias.

Comment: @RichardNeumann That question also doesn't refer to Sqlite. The  `__contains` postfix also doesn't seem to support SQL wildcards, even though Sqlite support them.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [raw](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/sql/#passing-parameters-into-raw) query like this:

```
 objs = MyModel.objects.raw(
     "SELECT * FROM myapp_mymodel WHERE text LIKE %s", ['%he_lo']
 )
 for obj in objs:
    # do something
```

Comment: @cerin if this fixed your issue don't forget to mark it as accepted.