# Filtering in the dictionary list for the jsonfield in Django

Tags: django, postgresql, django-rest-framework, django-filters, django-jsonfield

I have a django model that uses json column.

```
class ClassName(models.Model):
    data = JsonField(default=dict, blank=True, null=True, )
```

This is the schema in the json field.

```
{
   "name": "foo",
   "thing":[
      {
        "id": "1",
        "key": "hello"
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "key": "world"
      }
   ]
}
```

Is it possible to search against one key value in the list of dictionaries using ILIKE (icontains) operator?
ClassName.objects.filter(data__thing__key__icontains="wo")

Maybe someone has faced this problem?
I will be glad of any considerations

`ClassName.objects.filter(data__thing__contains=[{'key':'world'}])` - works (but only contains)

`ClassName.objects.filter(data__thing__1__key__icontains='wo')` - works (but only with the indication of the element)

```
.raw(""" 
    SELECT DISTINCT id 
    FROM classname, json_array_elements(data::json -> 'thing') as i 
    WHERE i->> 'key' ILIKE '%%{}%%'  """.format('wo')
    ) - works (but only raw)
```

Comment: Similar: [Django lookup by JSONField array value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74617447/django-lookup-by-jsonfield-array-value)

Answer (score 2):

i think you can use __contains lookup to search for a specific key-value pair within a JSONField like this :

```
search_term = "wo"
query = ClassName.objects.filter(Q(data__thing__contains=[{"key__icontains": search_term}]))
```

this should work