# Django JSONField filter on complex JSON document with list of object

Tags: django, mariadb, django-orm

I work with Django 3.2 and MariaDB.
I have an **Product** Model with an **product_settings** field (typed as **JSONField** ).

With a queryset I want to retrieve all products with a type of deposit equals to building.

Example of truncated product_settings value :

```
{
    "resources": [
        {
            "resource_config": {
                "linked_to": {
                    "params": {
                        "deposit": {
                            "type": "building"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm trying with this queryset but it does not return any results :

```
Product.objects.filter(product_settings__resources__resource_config__linked_to__params__deposit__type="building")
```

Do you have any idea ?

I've already read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74617447/django-lookup-by-jsonfield-array-value) but mine is quite more complex and need another solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution.

I had to use **__contains** on **resources** key like this

```
Product.objects.filter(
    product_settings__resources__contains={
        "resource_config": {
            "linked_to": {
                "params": {
                    "deposit": {
                        "type": "building"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
)
```